# Symfony2 Class not found error in AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony

I have an exiting project in Symfony running on windows. Now I moved it to my laptop which runs Ubuntu 16.04. But when I try to do app/console it says that class was not found in AppKernel.

Here is the actual error message.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "PimSecurityBundle" from namespace "Pim\SecurityBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /var/www/html/pim/app/AppKernel.php:34
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /var/www/html/pim/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2675): AppKernel->registerBundles()
>   1 /var/www/html/pim/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2497): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
>   2 /var/www/html/pim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(70): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
>   3 /var/www/html/pim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(123): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   4 /var/www/html/pim/app/console(27): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
>   5 {m in /var/www/html/pim/app/AppKernel.php on line 34

I already run composer update several times, remove my vendor and update but nothing works.

Comment: Where is the class PimSecurityBundle located? What namespace does it have?

Comment: PimSecurityBundle is located at src/pim/SecurityBundle/ and the namespace is namespace Pim\SecurityBundle; Its working properly in windows, only when I moved it to ubuntu got this problem

Comment: Windows isn't case sensitive. You need to change the folder name from `pim` to `Pim`

Comment: I did what you mentioned, but still the error message occur.

Comment: Did you clear your application cache?

Comment: @Oldskool, yup I already did. I also run several composer update but nothing works.